# how to link GCC options to the arm MCU FPU datasheet?

Tags: gcc, embedded, arm

I have a STM32F406VG MCU, and I have an arm GCC. I use some strange arguments for the FPU I found through google to compile for my platform, but I can't find any reference document making the correspondence.

I use -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16, I have the datasheet telling me that I have a Cortex-M4F, but nothing about the FPU. I found some unhelpful document for GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html and some unhelpful document from ARM: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIAHHAFG.html

But I can't fine any precise definition to match this argument with my FPU. Is there some kind of giant table with all the part number and the corresponding precise FPU definition on the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine this information from a number of places. First you must identify which ARM processor you are looking at, then find the TRM for that processor. In this case, the Cortex-M4 TRM is available here:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0439d/DDI0439D_cortex_m4_processor_r0p1_trm.pdf

This tells you (Section 7) that the FPU in the Cortex-M4 is:

> an implementation of the single precision variant of the ARMv7-M
> Floating-Point Extension (FPv4-SP).

Looking at the ARMv7m architecture reference manual (Available behind a license at http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0403c/index.html) we can find out about the Floating Point architecture extensions in section A1.3. Here we also find this advice:

> Based on the VFP implementation options defined for the ARMv7-A and
> ARMv7-R architecture profiles, a full characterization of the ARMv7-M
> Floating-point extension is FPv4-SP-D16-M. Some software tools might
> require this characterization.

GCC doesn't add the 'm' to the end of the characterization, so this gets us to the option -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16.

For the meaning of VFPv4-d16 we must look at the ARMv7a architecture reference manual (behind a license here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0419c/index.html) where section A1.4.1 gives this definition:

> VFPv4 can be implemented with either thirty-two or sixteen doubleword
> registers, see Advanced SIMD and Floating-point Extension registers on
> page A2-56. Where necessary, these implementation options are
> distinguished using the terms:
>
> • VFPv4-D32, or VFPv4U-D32, for a
> thirty-two register implementation
>
> • VFPv4-D16, or VFPv4U-D16, for a
> sixteen register implementation.
>
> Where the term VFPv4 is used it
> covers both options.

Comment: (+1) if fpu is single precision why reference manuals mentions it as `FPv4-SP-D16-M`, I initially was under assumption that was a `gcc` name reuse for vfpv settings.

Comment: Thanks for this detective work, this company makes no sense in their documentation (and product naming for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

ARM's page for Cortex M4 tells it has a "Single precision floating point unit - IEEE 754 compliant" which corresponds to "fpv4-sp-d16" on gcc. d16 is for telling there are 32 sp registers.

http://mobile.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-m/cortex-m4-processor.php?tab=Specifications

Comment: Thanks, do you have any explanation on why -d16 means 32 registers? this is really not explicit.

Comment: d16 means 16 double width registers (i.e. 16x64-bit registers), these can also be viewed as 32 single width registers (32x32-bit registers).

Comment: @nraynaud I would give the same answer as commenter above. To my knowledge, `fpv4` defines fpu registers as 64 bits wide supporting both single and dual precision. However Cortex-M4 line uses fpv4 technology but limiting it to single precision. Since it is easy for `gcc` to use fpv4 settings for M4 as well, you end up specifying `fpv4-sp-d16`. You have 16 dual registers (64bit wide), 32 single registers (32bit wide), but you are limited to single precision.