# How should I cross-compile for the ARM Cortex-m4 STM32F407VGT6 with Clang?

Tags: arm, embedded, clang, cross-compiling, cortex-m

First, a brief detour to avoid the XY problem: I need to experiment with LLVM on an ARM board (the Discovery kit STM32F407G). So, I cloned and built the recent (and official?) [LLVM embedded toolchain for ARM](https://github.com/ARM-software/LLVM-embedded-toolchain-for-Arm) with Clang. Now I need to actually *compile* for my processor, which seems to be the **STM32F407VGT6**.

The toolchain provides a list of configuration files (to be passed to Clang with the `--config` option). For instance:

```
armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16.cfg         
armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16_semihost.cfg
armv7em_hard_fpv5_d16.cfg            
armv7em_hard_fpv5_d16_semihost.cfg   
armv7em_soft_nofp.cfg                
armv7em_soft_nofp_semihost.cfg       
armv7m_soft_nofp.cfg                 
armv7m_soft_nofp_semihost.cfg
```

Now my question is: **which one should I use?**

I read [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464556/how-to-link-gcc-options-to-the-arm-mcu-fpu-datasheet), but there are a couple of things I am not sure about.

- The [Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100166/0001/Floating-Point-Unit/About-the-FPU?lang=en) says: "The Cortex-M4 FPU is an implementation of the single precision variant of the ARMv7-M Floating-Point Extension (FPv4-SP)."
- The [ARM website](https://developer.arm.com/Processors/Cortex-M4) specifies the Cortex-M4 has the architecture Armv7E-M.

So, first question, **is my CPU an ARMv7-M or ARMv7E-M?**

- Looking at the question linked, it seems that **all** Cortex-M4 use `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16`. But in the list I have you can see that there are two options for that: `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16.cfg` and `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16_semihost.cfg`.

**What is the difference?**

Thanks!

---

For completeness, this is `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16.cfg`:

```
--target=arm-none-eabihf -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7em -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
-fno-exceptions
-fno-rtti
--sysroot <CFGDIR>/../lib/clang-runtimes/arm-none-eabi/armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16
<CFGDIR>/../lib/clang-runtimes/arm-none-eabi/armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16/lib/crt0.o
```

and this is `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16_semihost.cfg`:

```
--target=arm-none-eabihf -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv7em -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
-fno-exceptions
-fno-rtti
--sysroot <CFGDIR>/../lib/clang-runtimes/arm-none-eabi/armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16
<CFGDIR>/../lib/clang-runtimes/arm-none-eabi/armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16/lib/crt0-semihost.o
-lsemihost
```

Comment: I would look at the specific data sheet to tell me what ST actually implemented inside that particular chip/family. Also see this page of theirs:   https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/arm-32-bit-microcontrollers/arm-cortex-m4.html    _"The Armv7E-M architecture is built on the Armv7-M architecture from the Cortex-M3 core and offers additional DSP extensions, ..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there by yourself. It is correct that the cortex-m4 uses the armv7em architecture. As your own sources imply, the Cortex-M4 FPU is FPv4-SP, which leaves `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16.cfg` and `armv7em_hard_fpv4_sp_d16_semihost.cfg`. The former is  the general-use configuration without semihosting, the later incorporates the semihosting library.

Semihosting is a mechanism which implements IO-functions (eg. `printf`) such that they get transferred via an SWD debug probe from and to the host computer. [Here](https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/stm32/semihosting/) is a link with more information about semihosting.

If you don't plan on using semihosting, just pick the regular config.